# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeReanimated.EasingNode.linear')

Tags: javascript, react-native, floating-labels

What problem I get when I use "react-native-floating-label-input": "^1.3.9"
If you have any ways to use "react-native-floating-label-input", please give me (with the source code).
Image
[My problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tRB9f.png)

My code

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, View, Image} from 'react-native';
import { useTranslation,  } from 'react-i18next'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import styles from './style'
import images from '../../theme/images';
import { colors } from 'react-native-elements';
import { FloatingLabelInput } from 'react-native-floating-label-input';
interface SignInScreenProps {

}

const SignInScreen: React.FC<SignInScreenProps> = () => {

  const { t } = useTranslation()
  const navigation = useNavigation()
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState('')

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <Image source={images.logo}
        style={styles.logoStyle}>
        </Image>
      </View>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: colors.white, borderTopLeftRadius: 20, borderTopRightRadius: 20}}>
      <FloatingLabelInput
        label={'label'}
        value={phone}
        rightComponent={(
          <TouchableOpacity style={{ alignContent:'center', justifyContent:'center'}} onPress={()=>{console.log('X clicked')}}></TouchableOpacity>
        )}
        onChangeText={(val) => setPhone(val)}
      />
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

export default SignInScreen;
```

Comment: Did you get a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

### Version 1.3.5 or higher - react-native-reanimated v2

- All animations now are using react-native-reanimated v2, as it was
  officially released recently. Please follow the Software Mansion
  guide installation for the react-native-reanimated v2:
  https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/installation
- OBS.: if during Software Mansion installation guide your project
  won't build or builds but crashes on start, try removing node_modules
  folder.
- OBS. 2: if you don't want to use the new react-native-reanimated v2,
  do not upgrade to this version, install version 1.3.4 and
  react-native-reanimated@1.13.2

https://github.com/Cnilton/react-native-floating-label-input#version-135-or-higher---react-native-reanimated-v2